# How to only flush(sync) one component of boost filtering stream？

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I got three components in my filteringStream:

0. filter using asio and pipes to pipe data into another program, I have a thread read output of it and write the outout to nest filter in chain.
1. A Normal filter
2. outputFile

It all runs smoothly util I met EOF.

When encountering EOF from input I have two things to do:

1. flush the buffer of filter 0 so all input data get written into pipe.
2. close the pipe so I can actully send eof to another program.

The problem is **I can't just flush the first buffer without flushing the entire chain, which led concurrent flush and write of filter 1 and 2 (with the thread reading program output and write to next filter).** The sync_impl method of indirect_streambuf is private.
If I use reader thread to flush to avoid concurrency, the inputPipe may still be full and the flush will be stucking, with no thread avaiable to read data from outputPipe there will be a deadLock situation.